# IIS Shadow Copying

Tags: c#, .net, api, iis

I am running a Web API project with shadow copying off i.e

```
**hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false"**
```

in the web.config file.

Now all my data in the static class and the cache is getting cleared after some time
which is indicating that the application is getting restarted or recycled

All the things work fine if I remove the above tag from web.confg

Comment: I am running the project in visual studio 2015

Comment: That's exactly why you should not turn off shadow copying.